# Have AWS removed a feature receiving email via SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to receive emails via SES and save the content to S3. I followed the manual from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email-receipt-rules-console-walkthrough.html

Currently I am stuck with **Creating rule sets and receipt rules**

The manual tells us to

> 2. In the navigation pane, under Configuration, choose Email Receiving.

But there's no such a menu anymore.

[image]

After that, I've found an official youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxXIpPZzMd0 I've found that the menu from the video was completely changed. It seems like AWS has removed the **Email Receiving** already.

I try to search for **Receipt rule sets** in the AWS console but nothing's found.

So, Have AWS removed the feature already ?

Comment: Have you checked that you meet the Prerequisites mentioned on that page you linked? Ie for instance is your SES endpoint in a region, where receiving emails is supported?

Answer (score 1):

You must switch to us-east-1 region and the option 'Email receiving' will appear on the configuration menu. Seems like you're using a region that not support receiving rules.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).